# Move product price next to stock availability in WooCommerce on Mobile devices

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, media-queries

In WooCommerce, I'd like to move the price into the Add to cart widget/module so that it is Inline with the availability text.

In this screenshot, shows the desired position of price:

[image]

There's a lot of unused real estate there when viewing on mobile, and I want to economize on it for conversion rate optimization.

Ideally the price, availability and add to cart button would be visible on the first load without needing a scroll

I'm currently running Astra theme and Elementor Pro builder

I added a Transform Translate CSS to the styling, but I'd didn't send it to the right position. Code is embarrassing

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to customize the single product price location. The following code below will add a 2nd product price next to stock availability with an additional selector class "is_mobile" that will allow you to show or hide depending on the screen device with (CSS media queries).

The  PHP code (here for simple products type only):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_html', 'filter_simple_product_stock_html', 10, 3 );
function filter_simple_product_stock_html( $availability_html, $availability, $product ){
    // For simple products
    if ( $product && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        // Apend product price html to product availability html (stock)
        return sprintf( '<p class="%s">%s</p>%s',
            esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price is_mobile' ) ),
            $product->get_price_html(), 
            $availability_html
        );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

To make it work as expected you will have **to add those CSS** rules like:

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px)  {
    .product-type-simple p.price {
        display: none;
    }

    .product-type-simple p.price.is_mobile, 
    .product-type-simple p.stock {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .product-type-simple p.price.is_mobile {
        margin-right: 12px !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px)  {
    .product-type-simple p.price.is_mobile  {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

So on mobile devices the default product price will be hidden and it will display the 2nd cloned price next to the stock availability like:

[image]

Otherwise on other devices, it will show the default product price and will hide the 2nd cloned price.

Comment: It worked! Thank you ever so much 